# STM32 SPI Slave configuration

Tags: stm32, spi, stm32-hal

I'm trying to communicate betwenn two NucleoF303K8 boards via SPI.
One board is Master and is controlled by UART. It can send via SPI 3 kinds of messages:

1. `{0x01 0x00 0x00 0x00}` that means 'read value'
2. `{0x81 0x00 0x00 0x00}` that means 'set value = 0'
3. `{0x81 0x01 0x00 0x00}` that means 'set value = 1'

The other board is Slave. It sets (and gets) LED pin value depending on command.

Slave algorythm is as follows:

1. when `NSS_Pin` becomes low, `EXTI_Callback` is called, and starts recievemnt of 1 byte
2. After First byte is recieved, I guess if it is readout command or writein
3. if it is readback I use `SPI_DMA` to transmit value if it writein I use `SPI DMA` to receive value
4. when `NSS_Pin` gets to high level again, slave processes message if it was `writeIn` or just waits for another command if it was `readout`

Here is the code:

```cpp
extern DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi1_tx;
extern DMA_HandleTypeDef hdma_spi1_rx;
extern SPI_HandleTypeDef hspi1;


uint8_t txb[16] = {0x01,0xAA,0xBB};
uint8_t rxb[16] = {};
uint8_t code = 0;
uint8_t op = 0; // 0: idle, 1: readout, 2: writein

void readOut(){
    op = 1;
    HAL_SPI_Transmit_DMA(&hspi1, txb,3);
}
void receiveWriteIn(){
    op = 2;
    HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1, rxb, 3);
}
void processWriteIn(){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD3_GPIO_Port, LD3_Pin, (GPIO_PinState)rxb[0]);
}

void SystemLoad(){
    HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LD3_GPIO_Port,LD3_Pin,GPIO_PIN_SET);
    while(1){
    }
}

void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin){
    HAL_SPI_DMAStop(&hspi1);
    if(GPIO_Pin == NSS_Pin){
        if(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(NSS_GPIO_Port, NSS_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_RESET){
            op = 0;
            HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1,&code,1);
        }else{
            if(op == 2){
                processWriteIn();
            }
            op = 0;
            code = 0;
        }
    }
}

inline void mainCbk(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi){
    HAL_SPI_DMAStop(hspi);
    if(hspi == &hspi1){
        if(op == 0){
            if(code & 0x80){
                receiveWriteIn();
            }else{
                readOut();
            }
        }
    }
}

void HAL_SPI_TxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi){
    mainCbk(hspi);
}
void HAL_SPI_TxRxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi){
    mainCbk(hspi);
}
void HAL_SPI_RxCpltCallback(SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi){
    mainCbk(hspi);
}
```

Slave settings in CubeMX are:

1. 1 GPIO output (LED) and one EXTI
2. `SPI1` with `DMARX` (Priority high) and `DMATX`(priority Very High) and `NVIC` enabled for both DMA channels and SPI1 global interrupt
3. NVIC priority, Debug, SysTick, etc. with highest priority (0), EXTI and SPI1 global interrupt with lower priority (1)
4. HCLK is 64 MHz, PCLK1 is 32 MHz, PCLK2 is 64 MHz
5. SPI speed from Master device is 250 KBit/s

For some reason I have two main problems:

1. `writeIn` data migrates in `rxbuffer` cyclicaly. That `0x01` in 'set value = 1' appears in `rxb[0]` then in `rxb[1]`, `rxb[2]` and from beggining on each SPI message.
2. readout data, that slaves transmitts also acts strange:
   on first 2 messages I recieve on master device (and see with logic analyzer on the line) proper values:

`{0x00 0x01 0xAA 0xBB}`

but then something changes andit becomes

`{0xBB 0x01 0xAA 0xBB}` or

`{0xBB 0x00 0x01 0xBB}` or

`{0xBB 0x81 0xAA 0xBB}` and if I after readout try to writein it becomes like

`{0xBB 0xBB 0xBB 0xBB}`

though `rxb` that is in `HAL_SPI_Receive_DMA(&hspi1, rxb, 3);` is filled with 0

I've looked into SPI1.DR register, but it is 0, so I don't know what to think. I've tried to DMAStop on message TX and RX callbacks, also I've tried SPI_Abort.

I've mixed priority levels in different ways:

1. all equal
2. EXTI > SPI > DMARX > DMATX (and TX > RX)
3. DMATX > DMARX > EXTI = SPI
4. DMATX > DMARX > EXTI > SPI
5. DMATX > DMARX > SPI > EXTI

Also I've tried to use `HAL_SPI_Transmit_IT`, but had the same result even if DMA was disabled at all.

Theoretically it have to work correct as SPI buffer is filled before the next byte si going to be transmitted, but it seems to act very strange.

What is the proper way to configure my device? Or maybe MCU cannot be controlled in such a way, as it has to use software core, to process messages, and there is proper way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you make it work without DMA or interrupt? Go step by step.

SPI Echo example (1 byte command, 1 byte data, SPI_DataSize_8b / I set the slave select pin manually / If you need to separate reading and writing data, and need to implement setpoint readback, you can improve this code with FromMaster/ToMaster arrays) :

```
void SPI_Slave_Process(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, SPI_HandleTypeDef *hspi, uint8_t* FromMaster, uint8_t* ToMaster) {
    static uint8_t RxData;
    static uint8_t TxData;
    while(!(HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(GPIOx, GPIO_Pin))) {
        HAL_SPI_Receive(hspi, &RxData, 1, 2);
        TxData = RxData;
        HAL_SPI_Transmit(hspi, &TxData, 1, 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was as following: to start reception in interrupt/DMA mode, MCU needs some time. When master initiates communication, SPI peripheral pushes data from its register, and data is not cleared from buffer after transmission. So register will push the same data till DMA or core changes it.

Solution is in correct timer selection. All serial devices have dedicated timings in between setting CS low, and between sending different data. For MCU you need at least about 0.5ms between CS_low and data start and the same is between receiving opcode and other data